# CSS Help: floating an image inside a list item hides icon

Tags: css, html-lists, css-float

I have an image in a list item I need floated. Everything looks fine in FF/6+. Webkit and IE, however, show the list icon on top of the image. When I try floating the list item itself, the icon simply vanishes. Is there a CSS way around this issue? I tried wrapping the content in a span, and still no solution. I've removed some of the text in order to lighten the code here.

```
<ul class="leftList">
<ul>
    <li>Pillow menu to customize your night's sleep</li>
    <li>Complimentary bathroom amenities</li>
    <li><span class="special_needs_list_item"><a rel="tooltip nofollow" title="Tooltip - Lorem ipsum"><img src="http://teamsite-prod.rccl.com:8030/DOT/img/global/special_needs.png" alt=""></a> Some srooms in this category are wheelchair-accessible.</span></li>
</ul>
</ul>


#ccStateroomFeatures ul {
    float: left;
    width: 320px;
    margin-left: 15px;
    font-size: 12px;
}
#ccStateroomFeatures ul li {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
#ccStateroomFeatures .leftList {
    width: 490px;
    float: left;
}

#ccStateroomFeatures .leftList ul,
#ccStateroomFeatures .rightList ul {
    float: none;
    margin-left: 15px;
    width: auto;
}
#ccStateroomFeatures .leftList ul .special_needs_list_item {
    margin:0 0 20px -15px;
    padding-left:15px;

}
#ccStateroomFeatures .leftList ul .special_needs_list_item img {
    float:left;
    margin:3px 5px 0 15px;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:13px;
}
```

Comment: Why do you use `.leftList ul`? Isn't the element you apply this class to the ul already? Maybe `ul.leftList` is what you mean.

Comment: I cut a bit too much html from the code, apparently, but I hadn't realized that the ul was inside another ul (it's not my code and its badly formatted and I can't alter the formatting.) That's a clue, however.

Comment: For whatever reason, floating an element inside an LI seems to screw up the LI. I just retreated and fortunately, it's a small enough icon that with vertical-align:top and a negative bottom margin, it worked for what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do. Are you trying to have the image supplied be used instead of the list icon?

If so, you'll want to use list-style-type:none to deal with that. Then play around with the margins to get it to line up like you want.

Comment: No, I'm not trying to use the image instead of the icon. The list has regular icons, and we need to insert an image into the list, and have the text in the list item wrap around the image. So it needs a float. But when I float it, it screws up the display of the list item in non-Moz browsers.